# how to set value to angularjs constant file from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I have a module with constants defined inside it. I want to make modification to this constant value under some condition from controller so that this changed constant value can be used in other places. This is the sample of my constants file

```
angular.module('myapp').constant("Constantobject", {

    TOOL: "Jump",
    NAME: "cat",

})
```

how can I change the value of jump from controller.

Comment: The objective of constant is not change the value at the life cicle of application.

Comment: yes. But the application which I am working on is already developed by my  colleague, so half of the app is developed with this constant. Is there anyway I can make the change for the first time so that the value is set on the constant file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change values you shouldn't be using a `Constant` even if it allows you to change values.

Just replace your `Constant` with a `Factory`, it will work in the same way

**Constant**

```
angular.module('myapp').constant("Constantobject", {
  TOOL: "Jump",
  NAME: "cat",
})
```

**Factory** (you can even keep the name but that's not advisable)

```
angular.module('myapp').factory("Constantobject", function(){
  return {
    TOOL: "Jump",
    NAME: "cat"
  }
})
```

And on a controller you could just update the value by doing
`Constantobject.TOOL = 'some value'`

Even if you keep the `Constant` you can update it the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Since its like we should not use constant when we want to change the value. I have entirely changed the concept now.

Answer (score 0):

Since we should not use constant and change the value later on. I followed a different approach to solve my problem, by declaring few global variables.Thanks for your help.